# Problems with expected conditions

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing

I did a little test in the application of Mercado Libre and when the run does not lift the browser and then says "Empty suite". I couldn't tell why, I passed the code, thanks in advance...

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


class Test_001(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)
        self.driver.maximize_window()


    def Test_001(self):
        self.driver.get("http://www.mercadolibre.com.ar")
        self.element1 = "//*[@class='ajip']"
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, self.element1)))


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the method name from `def Test_001(self):` to `def test_001(self):`

Unit test will pickup the test cases only if it's starts with **`test`**.

Comment: It was that friend. I also set the entire environment back because I thought the problem was somewhere else. It was so simple but it serves as learning. Thank you...